# Array method inconsistent behaviour

Tags: arrays, ruby

I encountered weird behaviour of the Array method and I wonder if there is any reason for it? It looks like a bug in Ruby to me:

```
Array(1)
[1]
Array('')
[""]
Array({})
[] # ???
Array(nil)
[] # ???
```

when I passed `nil` or `{}` to Array, I expected to get an array with one element,  instead, I got an empty Array. Note that when I passed an empty string, it correctly (in my opinion) returns an array with one element. Could anyone explain the logic behind this behaviour?

I expect:

```
Array(nil) # => [nil]
Array({})  # => [{}]
```

which would be consistent with:

```
Array('')  # => ['']
```

Or another reasonable behaviour would be:

```
Array('')  # => []
```

which would be 'consistent' with:

```
Array(nil) # => []
Array({})  # => []
```

Comment: @DaveNewton I've updated the question to explicitly state what I expect

Comment: For hashes it would explicitly *not* be consistent since there's well-defined behavior on receiving a hash. I disagree with your `nil` "consistency" argument, but that's little more than opinion.

Comment: `Array([])` and `Array({})` exhibit the same behaviour. They're both array-esque containers.

Comment: Be very careful assuming you found a bug in a core class in any language. http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idm46227256017920 will help you.

Comment: I don't think "inconsequential" means what you think it does.

Answer (score 5):

For hashes the behavior is well-defined: the hash is broken up into key/value pairs, each pair in a "sub"-array. An empty hash has no key/value pairs, so it's an empty array. Little else makes sense; special-casing for an empty object would break the principle of least surprise.

For `nil` you could argue either way. Since `nil` isn't anything IMO an empty array makes sense.

Ultimately the answer is because that's what `.to_ary` and `.to_a` return. For `nil` I'd find an empty array more `nil`-y than an array with a single `nil` in it. For hashes I think it must be consistent with how non-empty hashes are converted to arrays.

Comment: It would be worth to mention how to achieve what OP wanted, and it can be done by clever usage of splat operator `[*value]` will always return array containing `value` or `value` if it is already an array.

Answer (score 2):

The function Array(x) tries to convert x to an array using the following logic:

1. Try to convert it implicitly using x.to_ary
2. Try to convert it explicitly using x.to_a
3. Convert it by wrapping it in an array, ie [x]

So individual objects dictate the logic for how they are converted to arrays. The reason `Array('')` is `['']` instead of `[]` is that strings have no `to_ary` or `to_a` method, as of ruby 1.9. I believe this change was made because there is no canonical way to convert a string to an array. Do you want it split up by line, by characters? etc.